# How to resolve KeyError: <variable> in Python?

Tags: python, list, file, keyerror

Hi I'm trying to open simple csv file with the header from an external file:

got next file named: **name.csv** with next content:

```
Leo,Days,Ju
Tomas,Lee,Bruce
Max,Perez,Smith
```

If I code:

```
import csv
sep = ','
with open('name.csv') as csvfile:
     fieldnames = ['name', 'paterno', 'materno']
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames)
     for row in reader:
         list = (row['name'], \
                 row['materno'])
         print (sep.join(list))
```

The result is desired like:

```
Leo,Ju
Tomas,Bruce
Max,Smith
```

But if got an extra file with headers named **hdr_name.txt** with:

```
['name', 'paterno', 'materno']
```

With this new code:

```
import csv
sep = ','
fieldnames =  open('hdr_name.txt', 'r').read()
with open('name.csv') as csvfile:
    print(fieldnames)
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        list = (row['name'], \
            row['materno'])
        print (sep.join(list))
```

Got as result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
KeyError: 'name'
```

But if I ask for 'name' in fieldnames, is there!

```
>>> 'name' in fieldnames
True
>>>
```

What I'm doing wrong, with opening header from external file ?

Comment: Just read your header so `fieldnames =  open('hdr_name.txt', 'r').readlines()`

Comment: @AndMar That unfortunately does not fix it, because the file contains a single line with a str'd list.

Comment: Yes, that's true(

Comment: More importantly, stop dumping the string representation of an object to a txt file and calling it serialization - **use pre-existing serialization formats**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fieldnames` is a string that looks like this:

```
"['name', 'paterno', 'materno']"
```

Naturally, a membership test will return true, but that does not imply `fieldnames` is a list. Remember, `file.read` returns a string - you still need to cast it to a list.

This doesn't appear to look like JSON, so I'd recommend `ast`:

```
import ast
with open('hdr_name.txt', 'r') as f:
     fieldnames = ast.literal_eval(f.read().strip())
```

Comment: Ok. found other of the multiple ways to do it, once I got the main idea! Thanks @COLDSPEED

`fieldnames =  eval(open('hdr_name.txt', 'r').read())`

Using `eval()`

Comment: @IsraelDiaz try to stay away from eval, it is unsafe compared to ast.

Comment: @COLDSPEED - Oky. got it! 10xs!

Comment: Just more info about it: from documentation states: `See ast.literal_eval() for a function that can safely evaluate strings with expressions containing only literals.` [ https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval ]